# keeping output after key is released c# XNA

Tags: c#, arrays, string, xna

I am currently working on a "Player Select" screen for a Beat em' up. I have an array of six strings (player one, player two...). The players current choice is highlighted and when they press the enter key I want a sub menu to appear giving them the option to cancel or confirm their decision.

My problem is getting the sub menu to stay beyond when the user releases the enter key. In the following code "Decide" is the name of the sub menu array. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Decide.Length; i++)
        {

        if (prevKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter) && !keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))

            spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, Decide[i], location, Color.White);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of triggering *directly* on the "Is the enter key down" condition (which obviously becomes false when they release the key), have pressing the key set some *other* variable:

```
//Update
if (prevKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter) &&  !keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
   displayConfirmMenu = true;

//Draw
if (displayConfirmMenu)
   DrawSprite(...);
```

In general, you shouldn't be checking UI state in your `Draw` call. The only checks you should do are against internal state.